# Why does the dataframe not display a table with the same columns?

Tags: python

I came across such a case. there is a data frame with the same columns and does not output the entire table.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {2:['Green','Blue'],
        2:['small','BIG'],
        2:['High','Low']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      2
0  High
1   Low
```

Comment: ``print(data)`` -> ``{2: ['High', 'Low']}`` you've used the same key for multiple values, so the last one wins. This has nothing to do with pandas, it's how ``dict`` works in general.

Comment: To see this, `print(data)` before you create the df.

Comment: Yes indeed I tried print(data) and saw {2: ['High', 'Low']}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary only supports Unique Keys (in Key-Value pairs)
So when you create a DataFrame using Dictionary, it will only consider the latest Key-Value pair if there is duplication in Key.
For any reason, you create DataFrame with the Same Column Headers, use following code -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Green','Blue'], ['small','BIG'], ['High','Low']], columns = [2,2])
print(df)
```

It will show entire table with same column headers